# Ignoring write queries from different clients for the same row in Cassandra

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, cassandra, nosql, spring-data-cassandra

I'm making a simple survey program.

```
INSERT INTO sosang_survey_list (partner_id,survey_id,content,coupon_id,end_date,respon_cnt,start_date,state,title) VALUES (56177c09-cc8e-47fa-bfd6-fa316655ddde,f1ce1520-cdbd-11eb-b799-2112347ce13a,[{question:'test',choice_list:[{answer:'test',cnt:0},{answer:'test2',cnt:0}]}],null,'2021-06-15',0,'2021-06-15',false,'testeste');
```

I use the above write query on the client (node.js) server that uses a different IP than mine. (The 'content' column is nested of user defined types.)

Then, my spring server increments the 'cnt' of the 'content' column by 1 through an update query for that row. but it doesn't work. It is obviously increased in the query response shown by Spring Boot, but 'cnt' is still 0 in the actual DB.

I thought it was a consistency problem, so I tried setting the consistency option to 'qurom' on the node server and 'all' on my spring server, but the same symptom.

The current server configuration has three nodes, each operating on a different IP,
SimpleStrategy and replication_factor is 3.

please give me a hint..

Below is the 'content' column composed of user defined types..

[ {
"question" : "title",
"choice_list" : [ {
"answer" : "answer1",
"cnt" : 0
}, {
"answer" : "answer2",
"cnt" : 0
} ]
} ]

Answer (score 0):

The reason `cnt = 0` in the database is you are explicitly setting the value to zero here:

```
INSERT INTO sosang_survey_list
  (...) 
  VALUES (..., [{question:'test',choice_list:[{answer:'test',cnt:0},{answer:'test2',cnt:0}]}],...)
```

If you have multiple clients/app instances writing to the database, they could be overwriting the row with zero over and over again. Cheers!